# Uncaught TypeError: rectangle.draw is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

So, I've been working on a small project which draws two rectangles that will keep on bouncing to each side of a canvas in which they're drawn. Now, that part worked but i had some really messy coding so i decided to approach it from a different angle and now I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: rectangle.draw is not a funtion.
I don't understand what causes this error of how to solve it, so help would be appreciated.

Rectangle:

```
function Rectangle(width, height, posX, posY, speedX, speedY, color)
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
    this.color = color;

    function move(){
        this.posX += this.speedX;
        this.posY += this.speedY;
    }

    function changeX(){
        this.speedX = -this.speedX;
    }

    function changeY(){
        this.speedY = -this.speedY;
    }

    function draw()
    {
        if (gameArea != null){
            gameArea.fillStyle = this.color;
            gameArea.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.speedX, this.speedY);
        }
    }

    function  getTop(){
        return this.posY;
    }

    function getRight(){
        return this.posX + this.width;
    }

    function  getBottom(){
        return this.posY + this.height;
    }

    function  getLeft(){
        return this.posX;
    }
}
```

main (executed after page is loaded):

```
function main()
{
    createRectangles();
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    gameArea = c.getContext("2d");
    rect1.draw();
    rect2.draw();
    pauseButton =  document.getElementById("pause");
    pauseButton.addEventListener("click",pause);
    document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click",reset);
}
```

and createRectangles:

```
function createRectangles()
{
    rect1 = new Rectangle(50,100,getRandomX(0),getRandomY(),getRandomSpeed(),getRandomSpeed(), "#FF0000");
    rect2 = new Rectangle(50,100,getRandomX(400),getRandomY(),getRandomSpeed(),getRandomSpeed(), "#0000FF");
}
```

the exact error I'm getting is Uncaught TypeError: rect1.draw is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are creating objects using a [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), you need to declare the inner methods on **that object**, not just have them exist within the function.

Meaning, instead of saying:

```
function Rectangle(width, height, posX, posY, speedX, speedY, color)
{
    // ...
    function draw()             // <--- This is just a function within a function 
    {
        if (gameArea != null){
            gameArea.fillStyle = this.color;
            gameArea.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.speedX, this.speedY);
        }
    }
    // ...
```

You attach that function (using `this`) to the object that is created when using a function constructor:

```
function Rectangle(width, height, posX, posY, speedX, speedY, color)
{
    // ...
    this.draw = function()    // <--- This adds the function as a method to any object you instantiate using new Rectagle()
    {
        if (gameArea != null){
            gameArea.fillStyle = this.color;
            gameArea.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.speedX, this.speedY);
        }
    }
    // ...
```

**NOTE**:

You need to do this for all methods you want to exist on the instantiated object.

Comment: alternatively, leave your functions declared as they are, and then `return { draw: draw, ... }`, including each of the functions that you wish to export.